# How to bind extra properties of partial class while executing sql query in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a sql query having dynamic where clauses:

```
 string qry= "select p.*,u.fname as username from Proforma p inner join users u on u.userid=p.userid where " + where1 + " and " + where2 + " and " + where3 + " order by p.userid,invoicedate desc";
```

I added extra property using this

```
namespace root.Models.db
{
    public partial class Proforma
    {
       public string username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to get data at once using this:

```
List<Proforma> pm = db.Database.SqlQuery<Proforma>(qry).ToList();
```

I was expecting it to get username from database and bind accordingly. But it is not working.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you getting? an empty list?

Comment: User and Performa are separate tables, so they should be separate entities. If you want to merge them into a single entity then I'd recommend using a view and mapping an entity to the view rather than an arbitrary SQL statement.

Comment: @JesusPocoata Am getting all the data from Proforma table but not username that is from users table.

Comment: @StevePy Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please tell me if I get data from proforma first and put into a list then how can I get username in the same list by joining that list and users table

Comment: @PriyankaBansal I've expanded out an example in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on setting up the User and Performa.

If the relationship is 1-to-1 with both tables sharing a PK of UserId:

```
public class User 
{
  public int UserId {get; set;}
   // .. other User fields.

  public virtual Performa Performa {get; set;}
}

public class Performa
{
  public int UserId {get; set;}
  // .. other Performa fields.

  public virtual User User {get; set;}
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
  public UserConfiguration()
  {
    ToTable("Users");
    HasKey(x => x.UserId)
      .Property(x => x.UserId)
      .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    HasRequired(x => x.Performa)
      .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.User);
  }
}

public class PerformaConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Performa>
{
  public PerformaConfiguration()
  {
    ToTable("Performas");
    HasKey(x => x.UserId)
      .Property(x => x.UserId)
      .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
  }
}
```

From there I would strongly recommend using ViewModels / DTO objects to pass back to calling views / code rather than passing back entities. This avoids all sorts of performance pain from lazy loading and reduces the amount of data traversing the wire from DB through to client..

```
var performaQuery = db.Database.SqlQuery<Proforma>(qry);
var viewModels = performaQuery.Select(x => new PerformaViewModel 
{
  UserId = x.UserId,
  PerformaName = x.Name,
  UserName = x.User.Name
}).ToList();
```

Using this approach you can probably reduce or eliminate the need for dynamic querying. If you have your entities mapped with relationships and wanted to load Performa by say a UserName vs. a PerformaName or InvoiceDate...

```
public IEnumerable<PerformaViewModel> LoadByCriteria(string userName = null, string performaName = null, DateTime? invoiceDate = null)
{
   var query = context.Performas.Where(x => x.IsActive); // Global filter example...
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
     query = query.Where(x => x.User.UserName == userName);
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(performaName))
     query = query.Where(x => x.PerformaName == performaName);
   if (invoiceDate.HasValue)
     query = query.Where(x => x.InvoiceDate == invoiceDate);

  var viewModels = query.Select(x => new PerformaViewModel 
  {
    UserId = x.UserId,
    PerformaName = x.Name,
    UserName = x.User.Name
  }).ToList();

  return viewModels;
}
```

That's just a basic example for composing Linq expressions. You would need to elaborate on the scope of the context, whether using a unit of work or DB Context scoped to the request and provided by an IoC container, or declared with a `using()` block. EF will execute that with a conditional WHERE clause with the applicable conditions ANDed together if necessary and return just the selected fields.